# typescript - What's wrong here

Tags: node.js, typescript

I'm new to TypeScript and I'm trying to import the fs package from node.js, however this syntax is wrong and I'm not sure what am I supposed to do.

```
import * as "fs" from "fs";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What `import` does is it puts imported expressions into identifiers - or JavaScript variables. You need the syntax for an *identifier* to put the `fs` namespace into:

```
import * as fs from "fs";
```

Doing `as "fs"` doesn't work because what follows the `as` must be the variable name to put the namespace into, not a string.

Comment: What about for node.js. My code outputs Cannot find module 'fs' or corresponding type declarations

Comment: Sounds like you haven't installed Node types. Do `npm install @types/node --save-dev`

Comment: Thank you! (I still cannot mark you as an answer as stackoverflow forces me to wait 6 more minutes)